# Howto: Implement an OnClickListener for ToggleButtons in AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener, togglebutton

In my android app, i made a custom Alert Dialog. It opens on a Button click. In that dialog there are 4 togglebuttons that should react like radiobuttons. i dont want to use radiobuttons for design reasons.

I can't get it done to implement an onClick Listener for those togglebuttons. I to get them in a way, that only one button can be 'On' and the rest of them should be off. (Like a RadioButton Group)

I can't currently upload an image with my reputation, so here is the xml instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Dlg_DrvPut"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/DrvPutDlgTitle"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="1dp"
    android:layout_y="3dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/DrvPutDlgDrvCap" />
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*"  >
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">"
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_hit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textOn="Hit"
            android:textOff="Hit"
            android:layout_column="0" >
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_left"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textOn="Left"
            android:textOff="Left"
            android:layout_column="1" />
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_right"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textOn="Right"
            android:textOff="Right"

            android:layout_column="2" />
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_miss"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textOn="Miss"
            android:textOff="Miss"
            android:layout_column="3" />
      </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/drvDst"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >
        </EditText>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="1dp"
    android:layout_y="3dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/DrvPutDlgPutCap" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/putDst"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:ems="10"
         android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can this be done?

I tried the mentioned onCheckedChangeListener but this seems to be unavailable in AlertDialogBuilder.
Here is the code which will be run through after the button ist pressed to show the alertdialog.
This is the now working code with an onCheckedChangeListener for each toggle button. The checked state is set to false for all the other toggle buttons if one of the buttons is checked by the user.

```
public void pDrvPutClick(View v) {
     final Button b = (Button) v;

      LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
     View dstView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dlg_drvput, null);

      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
     builder.setView(dstView);
     final EditText edit_ddst = (EditText) dstView.findViewById(R.id.drvDst);
     final EditText edit_pdst = (EditText) dstView.findViewById(R.id.putDst);
     final ToggleButton rb1 = (ToggleButton) dstView.findViewById(R.id.rb_hit); 
     final ToggleButton rb2 = (ToggleButton) dstView.findViewById(R.id.rb_left);
     final ToggleButton rb3 = (ToggleButton) dstView.findViewById(R.id.rb_right);
     final ToggleButton rb4 = (ToggleButton) dstView.findViewById(R.id.rb_miss);

    rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
     @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
     {
         if ( isChecked )
         {
             rb2.setChecked(false);
             rb3.setChecked(false);
             rb4.setChecked(false);
         }
     }
     });

     rb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
         @Override
             public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
         {
             if ( isChecked )
             {
                 rb1.setChecked(false);
                 rb3.setChecked(false);
                 rb4.setChecked(false);
             }
         }
         });
     rb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
         @Override
             public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
         {
             if ( isChecked )
             {
                 rb1.setChecked(false);
                 rb2.setChecked(false);
                 rb4.setChecked(false);
             }
         }
         });
     rb4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
         @Override
             public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
         {
             if ( isChecked )
             {
                 rb1.setChecked(false);
                 rb3.setChecked(false);
                 rb2.setChecked(false);
             }
         }
         });



     builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
             String ddst;
             ddst = edit_ddst.getText().toString();
             if (ddst=="") {
                ddst="Drive";    
             }else {
                 if (rb1.isChecked()){
                     ddst="H"+ddst;
                 }
                if (rb2.isChecked()){
                     ddst="L"+ddst;
                 }
                if (rb3.isChecked()){
                     ddst="R"+ddst;
                 }
                if (rb4.isChecked()){
                     ddst="M"+ddst;
                 }
             }
             String pdst;

             pdst = edit_pdst.getText().toString();
             if (pdst=="") {
                pdst="PutDst";   
             }
             b.setText(ddst+"\n"+pdst);


         }


     });
```

Comment: Why not use radiobuttons? Where is your onClickListener code?

Comment: I dont want the radiobuttons for design reasons... code is now above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use onCheckedChangeListener

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) d.findViewById(R.id.toggle_id);

toggleAlarm.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    if(isChecked)
    {
        //your code
    }
    else
    {
        //your code
    }
}
});
```

Comment: there seem to be no onCheckedChangeListener for alertdialog.builder

Comment: I finally managed to get the listener. do i have to do that for every button or can i somehow group them? I updated the code above.

Comment: Works fine if the OnClick is taken out of the layout xml file and there are OnCheckedChangeListeners for every ToggleButton. Working code above...